# Azure Storage Accounts bicep deployment fails for sku Standard_LRS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-bicep

I have the following bicep file for Azure Blobs Storage on the `Standard_LRS`

```
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: 'ifmsstorageaccount'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}
```

when deploying to azure I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ***"status":"Failed","error":***"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At
 least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for 
usage details.","details":[***"code":"Conflict","message":"***\r\n  
\"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": ***\r\n    \"code\": 
\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource 
operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n    
\"details\": [\r\n      ***\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed
\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation 
failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        
\"details\": [\r\n          ***\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest
\",\r\n            \"message\": \"***\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": ***\\r\\n    
\\\"code\\\": \\\"InvalidParameter\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": \\\"Pricing tier doesn't match the subscription's billing model. Read 
http://aka.ms/PricingTierWarning for more details. Operation Id: 
'ccfd950570ed8ac1dd3214b811d46933'\\\"\\r\\n  ***\\r\\n***\"\r\n      
    ***\r\n        ]\r\n      ***\r\n    ]\r\n  ***\r\n***"***,***"code":"Conflict","message":"***\r\n  \"status\": 
\"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": ***\r\n    \"code\": 
\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource 
operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n  
  \"details\": [\r\n      ***\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed
\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation
 failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        
\"details\": [\r\n          ***\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest
\",\r\n            \"message\": \"***\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": ***\\r\\n  
  \\\"code\\\": \\\"ParameterOutOfRange\\\",\\r\\n    \\\"message\\\": 
\\\"The value of the 'Sku.Name' should be in: [Standard_B1ms, 
Standard_B1s, Standard_B2s, Standard_B4ms, Standard_B8ms, 
Standard_D16s_v3, Standard_D2s_v3, Standard_D32s_v3, Standard_D4s_v3, 
Standard_D64s_v3, Standard_D8s_v3, Standard_E16s_v3, Standard_E2s_v3, 
Standard_E32s_v3, Standard_E4s_v3, Standard_E64s_v3, Standard_E8s_v3, 
Standard_M128ms, Standard_M128s, Standard_M64ms, Standard_M64s, 
Standard_E48s_v3, Standard_D2ds_v4, Standard_D4ds_v4, Standard_D8ds_v4, 
Standard_D16ds_v4, Standard_D32ds_v4, Standard_D48ds_v4, 
Standard_D64ds_v4, Standard_E2ds_v4, Standard_E4ds_v4, Standard_E8ds_v4,
 Standard_E16ds_v4, Standard_E32ds_v4, Standard_E48ds_v4, 
Standard_E64ds_v4, Standard_D48s_v3, Standard_E20ds_v4, Standard_M8ms, 
Standard_M16ms, Standard_M32ts, Standard_M32ls, Standard_M32ms, 
Standard_M64ls, Standard_M64, Standard_M64m, Standard_M128, Standard_M128m, Standard_B12ms, Standard_B16ms, Standard_B20ms, 
Standard_D2ads_v5, Standard_D4ads_v5, Standard_D8ads_v5, 
Standard_D16ads_v5, Standard_D32ads_v5, Standard_D48ads_v5, 
Standard_D64ads_v5, Standard_D96ads_v5, Standard_E2ads_v5, 
Standard_E4ads_v5, Standard_E16ads_v5, Standard_E20ads_v5, 
Standard_E32ads_v5, Standard_E48ads_v5, Standard_E64ads_v5, 
Standard_E96ads_v5, Standard_D2_v5, Standard_D4_v5, Standard_D8_v5, 
Standard_D16_v5, Standard_D32_v5, Standard_D48_v5, Standard_D64_v5, 
Standard_D96_v5, Standard_D2s_v5, Standard_D4s_v5, Standard_D8s_v5, 
Standard_D16s_v5, Standard_D32s_v5, Standard_D48s_v5, Standard_D64s_v5,
 Standard_D96s_v5, Standard_D2ds_v5, Standard_D4ds_v5, Standard_D8ds_v5,
 Standard_D16ds_v5, Standard_D32ds_v5, Standard_D48ds_v5, 
Standard_D64ds_v5, Standard_D96ds_v5, Standard_E2ds_v5, 
Standard_E4ds_v5, Standard_E8ds_v5, Standard_E16ds_v5, 
Standard_E20ds_v5, Standard_E32ds_v5, Standard_E48ds_v5, 
Standard_E64ds_v5, Standard_E96ds_v5, Standard_E104ids_v5, 
Standard_E2bds_v5, Standard_E4bds_v5, Standard_E8bds_v5, 
Standard_E16bds_v5, Standard_E32bds_v5, Standard_E48bds_v5, 
Standard_E64bds_v5]. Verify that the specified parameter value is 
correct.\\\"\\r\\n  ***\\r\\n***\"\r\n          ***\r\n        ]\r\n   
***\r\n    ]\r\n  ***\r\n***"***,***"code":"Conflict","message":"***\r\n 
 \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": ***\r\n    \"code\": 
\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource 
operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n  
  \"details\": [\r\n      ***\r\n        \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed
\",\r\n        \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation
 failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.\",\r\n        
\"details\": [\r\n          ***\r\n            \"code\": \"BadRequest
\",\r\n            \"message\": \"***\\r\\n  \\\"error\\\": ***\\r\\n  
  \\\"code\\\": \\\"InvalidValuesForRequestParameters\\\",\\r\\n    
\\\"message\\\": \\\"Values for request parameters are invalid: kind, 
sku. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/storageaccounttypes\\\"
\\r\\n  ***\\r\\n***\"\r\n          ***\r\n        ]\r\n      ***\r\n  
  ]\r\n  ***\r\n***"***]***
```

and I don't know how to tell which of these are `Standard_LRS`

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Those are virtual machine sizes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BlockBlobStorage` kind is part of the [Premium SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-block-blob-premium).

In order for the storage account to be deployed, you would need to slightly amend your configuration so that the `SKU name` matches the chosen `kind` configuration:

```
resource storage_account 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'ifmsstorageaccount'
  location: location
  
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }

  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
}
```

This should allow you to deploy the storage account. The displayed VM SKUs are strange but I assume that you also have some further configurations in your bicep file that are the cause for that particular error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

According to [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#property-values), location should be string in your code like East US or West US.

**Main.bicep:**

```
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01'= {
  name: 'venkat9874'
  location: 'East US'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}
```

The above Bicep file is deployed with using PowerShell.

**Commands:**

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -TemplateFile Main.bicep -ResourceGroupName <your resource grp>
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: You have selected the `StorageV2` kind, which is different from OP's config since it can be deployed in the `Standard` SKU. `BlockBlobStorage` - like in OP's config - can only be deployed into the `Premium` SKU.

Comment: yeah, you are correct. But If Op needs to deploy in `Standard_LRS` sku he needs to config `storageV2` kind.

Comment: Fair point - you're right. I assumed that `BlockBlobStorage` was specifically selected on purpose but if OP requires Standard SKU, then `StorageV2` or `BlobStorage` would suit as well.